# EF Code first one way navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have the following entities:

```
[KnownType(typeof(Script))]
public class Application : IEntity
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long? StartScriptID { get; set; }
    // Other properties...

    // Navigation properties:
    public virtual Script StartScript { get; set; }   // new
    public virtual List<Script> Scripts { get; set; }
}

[KnownType(typeof(Application))]
public class Script : IEntity
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // Other properties...

    // Navigation properties:
    public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
}
```

I have no fluent configurations on the `DbContext`

So the model exists of Scripts which must be bound to an application. Applications can have a startScript defined. All this I already have working.

Now I am in need of a navigation property: `Application.StartScript`.

The question is how can I add the navigation property on `Application` **without** having to add a the equivalent navigation property on `Script`.

Thanks in advance!

---

EDIT: When I run Add-Migration the following migration code is generated:

```
public override void Up()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Scripts", "ApplicationID", "dbo.Applications");
    AddColumn("dbo.Scripts", "Application_ID", c => c.Long());
    CreateIndex("dbo.Applications", "StartScriptID");
    CreateIndex("dbo.Scripts", "Application_ID");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Applications", "StartScriptID", "dbo.Scripts", "ID");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Scripts", "Application_ID", "dbo.Applications", "ID");
}
```

This creates a new column on Scripts which I don't need, as I already have the StartScriptID column.

EDIT: Update after @haim770 answer

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Application>().HasOptional(x => x.StartScript).WithOptionalDependent(x => x.Application);
}

public override void Up()
{
    DropForeignKey("dbo.Scripts", "ApplicationID", "dbo.Applications");
    DropIndex("dbo.Scripts", new[] { "ApplicationID" });
    RenameColumn(table: "dbo.Applications", name: "ApplicationID", newName: "StartScript_ID");
    AddColumn("dbo.Scripts", "Application_ID", c => c.Long());
    CreateIndex("dbo.Applications", "StartScript_ID");
    CreateIndex("dbo.Scripts", "Application_ID");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Scripts", "Application_ID", "dbo.Applications", "ID");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Applications", "StartScript_ID", "dbo.Scripts", "ID");
}
```

It doesn't understand that it should use the already existing StartScriptID. Is there a way to point it in the right direction?

EDIT: Wanted database structure:

Applications:

- ID, PK, bigint, not null
- Name, nvarchar(max), not null
- StartScriptID, bigint, null

Scripts:

- ID, PK, bigint, not null
- Name, nvarchar(max), not null
- ApplicationID, FK, bigint, not null

EDIT:

```
public class Application
{
    [InverseProperty("StartScript")]
    public long? StartScriptID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StartScriptID")]
    public virtual Script StartScript { get; set; }
}
```

I was thinking there was no changes needed in the database, so I have tried adding migration with -IgnoreChanges. But then I got an `EntityCommandExecutionException` when querying for entities: "Invalid column name 'Application_ID'". So the Entity Framework needs some configuration for telling to use the `StartScriptID` property.

Comment: What's happening when you *do* add the `StartScript` property?

Comment: What exactly is your desired tables structure?

Comment: okay, i am still not sure what exactly is the problem. You have a 0..1 relation, which will get a Key either way. Do you want to have only a one-way key? Do you want to customize the column name?

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster I basically want a 1..1 relation but not having to have the nav property on Script, as I won't be needing it. And also it would always have the same value as `Script.Application`

Comment: Then, simply add only the one navigation Property and add a ForeignKey Attribute to it, referring to the ID Property of the same class.

Comment: @LazyTarget Did I help ? EF is creating `Application_ID` inside `Scripts` because application has a list of `Scripts`. If you don't want this relation, remove the list. Otherwise you will need the `Application_ID`

Comment: @MalGaniS I now realize I don't need Entity Framework for the navigation property that I want. I could simply create a regualar get accessor which gets the script with equal ID as StartScriptID. And adding the `NotMappedAttribute` to ignore the property from Entity Framework. Thank you everyone for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the mapping using the [ForeignKeyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [InversePropertyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.inversepropertyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
If that doesn't work the way you want, you can always edit the migration yourself before applying it.

If you want to customize the column name, try the ColumnAttribute:

```
public class Application
{
    [Column("DatabaseColumnName")]
    public long? StartScriptID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StartScriptID")]
    public virtual Script StartScript { get; set; }
}
```

A longer explanation can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/data/gg193958.aspx

Comment: Setting the `ForeignKeyAttribute` on Application.StartScript doesn't change the migration output.

Comment: Sure I can edit the migration, however won't Entity Framework consider the model as different than the database structure?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [EntityTypeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696117(v=vs.113).aspx) It makes more easy to handle this kind of problem. Then:

```
public class Application 
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long? StartScriptID { get; set; }
    // Other properties...

    // Navigation properties:
    public virtual Script StartScript { get; set; }   // new
    public virtual ICollection<Script> Scripts { get; set; }
}

public class Script 
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    // Other properties...

    // Navigation properties:
    public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Application>
{
    public ApplicationMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.ID);

        this.ToTable("TB_APLICATION", "aplication");

        this.Property(t => t.ID).HasColumnName("id");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("name");
        this.Property(t => t.StartScriptID).HasColumnName("startscript_id");

        this.HasOptional(t => t.StartScript)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.StartScriptID);
    }
}

public class ScriptMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Script>
{
    public ScriptMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.ID);

        this.ToTable("TB_APLICATION", "aplication");

        this.Property(t => t.ID).HasColumnName("id");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("name");

        this.HasRequired(t => t.Application)
            .WithMany(w => w.Scripts)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.ApplicationId);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to tell EF about the Mappings: (Call it inside *OnModelCreating*)

```
public static class MappingConfig
{
     public static void ConfigureMap(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
         modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationMap());
         modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ScriptMap());
     }
 }
```